# Undefined references to std::streambuf methods when building wxWidgets with Clang on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, clang, wxwidgets, linker-errors

I've been trying to build my app (with wxWidgets) using Clang (with MSVC libraries). But I keep getting these linking errors. I used to build the app using minGW and it worked just fine.

These are the errors:

```
graphics.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: void __cdecl std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setp(char *,char *,char *)" (__imp_?setp@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IEAAXPEAD00@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual in
t __cdecl std::basic_stringbuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::overflow(int)" (?overflow@?$basic_stringbuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@MEAAHH@Z)
graphics.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::locale __cdecl std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::getloc(void)const " (__imp_?getloc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEBA?AVlocale@2@XZ) referenced in function "public: clas 
s std::basic_filebuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __cdecl std::basic_filebuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::open(char const *,int,int)" (?open@?$basic_filebuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAPEAV12@PEBDHH@Z)
shaders.o : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::locale __cdecl std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::getloc(void)const " (__imp_?getloc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEBA?AVlocale@2@XZ)
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1120 (use -v to see invocation)
graphics.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __cdecl std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::snextc(void)" (__imp_?snextc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAHXZ) referenced in function "class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::c 
har_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::getline<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &&,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &,char)" (??$getline@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$all 
ocator@D@2@@std@@YAAEAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@$$QEAV10@AEAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@D@Z)
shaders.o : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __cdecl std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::snextc(void)" (__imp_?snextc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAHXZ)
make: *** [main.exe] Error 1120
shaders.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::fpos<struct _Mbstatet> __cdecl std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::pubseekoff(__int64,int,int)" (__imp_?pubseekoff@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAA?AV?$fpos@U_Mbstatet@@@2 
@_JHH@Z) referenced in function "public: class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::seekg(__int64,int)" (?seekg@?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@_JH@Z)
shaders.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __int64 __cdecl std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sgetn(char *,__int64)" (__imp_?sgetn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAA_JPEAD_J@Z) referenced in function "public: class std::basic_ 
istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::read(char *,__int64)" (?read@?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@PEAD_J@Z)
.\build\main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
```

I have wxWidgets v3.1.5, Clang v13.0.1 and MSVC v143

I am using this makefile:

```
CXX := clang++
CXXFLAGS := -Winvalid-pch -Wall -Wextra --std=c++17
CXXFLAGS := -DWXUSINGDLL -D_UNICODE -D__WXMSW__ -DNDEBUG

OUTPUT := main.exe

SRC_DIR = ./src
BUILD_DIR = ./build

CXXFLAGS += -isystem./include/msvc -isystem./include
LDFLAGS := -L./lib/vc_x64_dll
LDFLAGS += -L./lib/glew
LDFLAGS +=  -lopengl32
LDFLAGS += -lglew32

SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJS := $(SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)

DEPS := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.hpp)

all: $(OUTPUT)

$(OUTPUT): $(OBJS)
    @echo linking...
    @$(CXX) -o ./build/$@ $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)

.PHONY: all

%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    @echo $(CXX) -c $<
    @$(CXX) $< -c -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS)
```

I've tried this on Windows 11 as well as Windows 10, both with the same outcome.

Comment: @Albert21, what is the value of `LDFLAGS`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Igor I forgot to change the assignment operator of the first mention into just assignment operator. Previously I was using this linker flag for minGW: `LDFLAGS := -Wl,-subsystem,windows`.

Comment: @Albert121, so it compiles now?

Comment: @Igor No, the makefile is like this. I just forgot to change `+=` to `:=`. But it does not make any difference - adding to string that was not set to any value before is the same like setting the string.

Comment: @Albert121, so what is the value of `LDFLAGS`?

Comment: @Igor As it is said in the post. If you add it all up: `LDFLAGS := -L./lib/vc_x64_dll -L./lib/glew -lopengl32 -lglew32`

Comment: @Albert121, can you try to build the `pyramid` sample that comes with wxWidgetsusing the compiler in question and see what it will link with?

Comment: @Igor `pyramid` sample builds and works fine with this makefile